# Replace Get-Service value

Tags: powershell

I am creating an HTML report and using excellent libraries/code from [Thomas Franke](http://www.thomas-franke.net/powershell-creating-html-reports/)

Problem I am having is that I want the get-services to return a list of 3 services and if 1 of those services is "stopped", I want to wrap that value with HTML tags `<b>stopped</b>`.

My code looks like this:

```
Object = Get-Service -ComputerName $theServer -Include sftlist,sftvsa,TermService,LanmanServer,Netlogon | Select-Object DisplayName,Name,Status | ForEach-Object {-replace "Status=Running", "<b>Status=Stopped</b>" }
```

Does anyone have any idea how I can accomplish this?  Your help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to replace the text "Status=Stopped" with `"<b>Status=Stopped</b>"`?

This code sample will accomplish that goal:

```
Get-Service -ComputerName $theServer -Include sftlist,sftvsa,TermService,LanmanServer,Netlogon | 
Select-Object DisplayName,Name,Status| ForEach-Object {
   if ($_.Status -ne 'Running'){
        $_ -replace "Status=Stopped", "<b>Status=Stopped</b>"
    }
   else{$_}}
```

The key here if just to add an If statement to check and see if the Status of each Service object is Not Equal to Running.  If it isn't, we replace the text with `<b>Status=Stopped</b>` and continue.  If the service is running, we just list the object as it is, using `else{$_}`.

The result is not pretty PowerShell code though, so I hope that the tool you're using know how to deal with HTML in a PS Object.

Comment: Thank you very much.  I do see what you mean by ugly. 
My results look like this:
Netlogon          Running

@{DisplayName=BranchCache; Name=PeerDistSvc; <b>Status=Stopped</b>}

Not sure why the @{DisplayName=... is appearing in front of the second service result.  Thank you anyway for the assistance.